# UnityEditor.ObjectPreview was not disposed properly - Unity 2021.3.9f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, blender

I'm pretty new to Unity, still learning this game engine. I wanted to try making a basic scene with barrels that I model in Blender, I followed this tutorial [GAME ASSET BEGINNER TUTORIAL - Exporting from Blender to Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhJ8EJ_GtLI) and everything goes fine until I came across this error.

[Console error Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuhGu.png)

```
UnityEditor.ObjectPreview was not disposed properly. Make sure that base.Cleanup is called if overriding the Cleanup method. If you are implementing this in an Editor or EditorWindow, don't forget to call ObjectPreview.Cleanup in OnDisable.

UnityEditor.ObjectPreview:Finalize ()
```

I tried to find a solution but I couldn't find anything that could fix this error. On some Reddit thread, I found that a problem might be in mesh Normals, I already recalculate it in my Blender project but the same thing happens.
Although my barrel model looks just fine on the scene, I want to know what this error means.

I'm using Blender 3.2.2 and my Unity project is on Unity version 2021.3.9f1

[Barrel model on the scene Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBMkO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You must delete camera and something like that in blender, and setting export in bake animation at the bottom remove the check mark NLA Strips and All Actions [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqccO.png)